# Specify multifield with different analyzer for list of strings

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with a property `aliases` that is a list of strings. I want to specify multifields based on that list so I can search it with the appropriate language analyzes.

But using this mapping:

```
'names':{
    'type':'object',
    'fields': {
        'native': {
            'type': 'text', <- I guess this doesn't even make sense
            'analyzer': 'en'
        }
    }
}
```

Is it achievable? I know it's possible to have dynamic mappings, but I don't know how to use that in this problem. I also read the documentation on nested objects and it comes close to give me a solution, but it's not a perfect fit unless I make each string into an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

Arrays of strings are mapped the same way as regular text. This means that in the mapping you just have to specify `'type': 'text'` instead of `'type':'object'` and everything works as expected.

## Rationale

The docs about arrays has the following text box:

> The fact that all field types support multi-value fields out of the box is a consequence of the origins of Lucene. Lucene was designed to be a full text search engine. In order to be able to search for individual words within a big block of text, Lucene tokenizes the text into individual terms, and adds each term to the inverted index separately.
>
> This means that even a simple text field must be able to support multiple values by default. When other datatypes were added, such as numbers and dates, they used the same data structure as strings, and so got multi-values for free.

In fact, if you just create any document with an array of strings and `GET` the mapping created dynamically, you'll see something similar to

```
{'fields': {'keyword': {'ignore_above': 256, 'type': 'keyword'}},
            'type': 'text'}
```

Which is the same as you would get for a regular text field.